# How to Write Generic Numeric Function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I know this question may be answered a lot of times, however I cannot find a post that can solve my question. My question is I want to write a generic function that can take `Int`, `Double` or `BigDecimal` and do the calculation.

```scala
def foo[T: Numeric](returns: Seq[T])(implicit ev: T => Ordered[T]): Seq[T]= {
    returns.filter(_ >= 0)
}
```

However I got a Type Match error, because `0` is a `Int`. If there any way that can make it work for any `Numeric` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
def foo[T](returns: Seq[T])(implicit N: Numeric[T]): Seq[T] = {
  import N._
  returns.filter(_ >= N.zero)
}
```

The [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Would rather ...

```scala
def foo[T](returns: Seq[T])(implicit n: Numeric[T]): Seq[T] =
  returns.filter { v => n.compare(v, n.zero) >= 0 }
```